# How to take draw an average line for a scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

My data is the following:

```
x = [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9]
y = [6,5,4,3,2,1,1,2]
```

And I can obtain the following two graphs.

[image]

and

[image]

However, what I want is *this* (an average of all the points along the way):
[image]

Is it possible in matplotlib? Or do I have to change the list manually and somehow create:

```
x = [3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
y = [6,5,4,3,2,1,1.5]
```

**RELEVANT CODE**

```
ax.plot(x, y, 'o-', label='curPerform')
x1,x2,y1,y2 = ax.axis()
x1 = min(x) - 1 
x2 = max(x) + 1
ax.axis((x1,x2,(y1-1),(y2+1)))
```

Comment: I think you have to create the data manually. As a general rule, matplotlib only plots data you already have, it doesn't perform any calculation on data before plotting.

Comment: @heltonbiker Yea, I was afraid that'd be the answer =/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you must do the calculation yourself.  `plot` plots the data you give it.  If you want to plot some other data, you need to calculate that data yourself and then plot that instead.

Edit:  A quick way to do the calculation:

```
>>> x, y = zip(*sorted((xVal, np.mean([yVal for a, yVal in zip(x, y) if xVal==a])) for xVal in set(x)))
>>> x
(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
>>> y
(6.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.5)
```

Comment: Ugh, I was afraid of that. Any suggestions on how I'd do that? I was thinking that best would be to go through my x-list, find all the duplicates (could be many), get the index of all duplicates and make an average of the indexes in the y-list.

Comment: You could do it with a decorator, so it would 'fairly' invisible.

Comment: @BrenBarn I'm getting a Syntax Error when I try to print x or y (though the zip line itself doesn't give any errors) . I assume np is numpy? - Sorry, I'm still a beginner =/

Comment: Yes, np is numpy.  If you have some other problem you'll need to give the traceback (maybe ask a separate question).  Is it possible you're using Python 3?  In Python 3 `print` became a function so you'll get a syntax error from `print x`; you need `print(x)` instead.

Comment: @BrenBarn o wait, I got it. I was missing a bracket :). THANK YOU SO MUCH! :D

Comment: @Wysek Your comment prompted me to, at last, read about decorators in python. Very enlightening!

Answer (score 39):

This can done by generating a new `y_mean` from your data, then plotting this on the same plot axis using an additional call to `ax.plot()`, where:

- `x` is the same `x` used in your scatter plot
- `y` is an iterable with "mean" value you calculate repeated so that its length is equal to `x`, i.e. `y_mean = [np.mean(y) for i in x]`.

**Example**:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import numpy as np


# Create some random data
x = np.arange(0,10,1)
y = np.zeros_like(x)    
y = [random.random()*5 for i in x]

# Calculate the simple average of the data
y_mean = [np.mean(y)]*len(x)

fig,ax = plt.subplots()

# Plot the data
data_line = ax.plot(x,y, label='Data', marker='o')

# Plot the average line
mean_line = ax.plot(x,y_mean, label='Mean', linestyle='--')

# Make a legend
legend = ax.legend(loc='upper right')

plt.show()
```

**Resulting figure**:
[image]

Comment: Minor thing but I think stating it as `y_mean = [np.mean(y) for i in y]` (instead of your unrelated var 'x') would be clearer.

Comment: I was thinking one value of `y` (or its mean) to every value of `x`, which I why I wrote it this way. They both have the same length, so either works fine as you mentioned.

Comment: Is there a way we can add the value of the mean as a text?

Comment: In the legend? You could simply do `label=str(y_mean[0])`

Comment: If you want it on the line someplace, you would use an [annotation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/annotation_demo.html).